# WM_DEVICECHANGE Messages Are Not Sent to WndProc - C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, usb, device, windows-messages

My application creates a window for the purpose of handling the `WM_DEVICECHANGE` Windows message.  `WndProc` does get called several times, until my application calls a function to poll for keyboard events, but for whatever reason it does not get called when I remove or insert my USB device.

This is the GUID for my USB device.  I'm sure it's correct:

```
static const GUID _guidForCP210xDevices = {
    0xA2A39220, 0x39F4, 0x4B88, 0xAE, 0xCB, 0x3D, 0x86, 0xA3, 0x5D, 0xC7, 0x48
};
```

This is how my window is created:

```
m_hInstance = ::GetModuleHandle( NULL );

if ( m_hInstance == NULL )
{
    TRACE(_T("CNotifyWindow::CNotifyWindow : Failed to retrieve the module handle.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), ::GetLastError(), __WFILE__, __LINE__);
    THROW(::GetLastError());
}

m_wcx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);  // size of structure
m_wcx.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; // initially minimized
m_wcx.lpfnWndProc = &WndProc;       // points to window procedure
m_wcx.cbClsExtra = 0;               // no extra class memory
m_wcx.cbWndExtra = 0;               // no extra window memory
m_wcx.hInstance = m_hInstance;      // handle to instance
m_wcx.hIcon = ::LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION ); // default app icon
m_wcx.hCursor = ::LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW ); // standard arrow cursor
m_wcx.hbrBackground = NULL;         // no background to paint
m_wcx.lpszMenuName = NULL;          // no menu resource
m_wcx.lpszClassName = _pwcWindowClass; // name of window class
m_wcx.hIconSm = NULL;               // search system resources for sm icon

m_atom = ::RegisterClassEx( &m_wcx );

if ( m_atom == 0 )
{
    TRACE(_T("CNotifyWindow::CNotifyWindow : Failed to register window class.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), ::GetLastError(), __WFILE__, __LINE__);
    THROW(::GetLastError());
}

m_hWnd = ::CreateWindow(
    _pwcWindowClass,
    _pwcWindowName,
    WS_ICONIC,
    0,
    0,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    m_hInstance,
    NULL
    );

if ( m_hWnd == NULL )
{
    TRACE(_T("CNotifyWindow::CNotifyWindow : Failed to create window.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), ::GetLastError(), __WFILE__, __LINE__);
    THROW(::GetLastError());
}

::ShowWindow( m_hWnd, SW_HIDE );    // function does not fail

if ( RegisterForNotification() != ERROR_SUCCESS )
{
    TRACE(_T("CNotifyWindow::CNotifyWindow : Failed to register for device notification.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), ::GetLastError(), __WFILE__, __LINE__);
    THROW(::GetLastError());
}
```

This is how I register for device notification:

```
static DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE dbt = {0};

ASSERT(m_hWnd != NULL);

// Populate DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE structure.
dbt.dbcc_size = sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE);
dbt.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
dbt.dbcc_classguid = _guidForCP210xDevices;

// Register for HID devic notifications
m_hNotify = RegisterDeviceNotification( m_hWnd, &dbt, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE );

if ( m_hNotify == NULL )
{
    TRACE(_T("CNotifyWindow::RegisterForNotification : Failed to register for device notification.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), ::GetLastError(), __WFILE__, __LINE__);
    return ::GetLastError();
}

return ERROR_SUCCESS;
```

My `WndProc` function looks like this:

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    DEV_BROADCAST_HDR * pHeader = reinterpret_cast<DEV_BROADCAST_HDR *>(lParam);

    switch ( uMsg )
    {
    case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
        if ( pHeader != NULL )
        {
            if ( pHeader->dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_PORT )
            {
                OnDeviceChange( wParam );
            }
        }
        break;

    default:
        // Do nothing.
        break;
    }

    return ::DefWindowProc( hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam );
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: You say the WndProc works 'until my function to poll for keyboard events is called'. That implies that you are preventing the message pump from processing any further messages - your device notifications included. It's pretty clear that you've excised some code here for clarity, so it's hard to tell if this is the actual problem.

Comment: Are you still trying to run WndProc in a worker thread?

Comment: @Jon: My apologies, it was supposed to say, "...until my application calls a function to poll for keyboard events."  The typo has been fixed.  In regards to the message pump, what is that?  Does it operate/call `WndProc` asynchronously?

Comment: @John Dibling: No, per your suggestion, I've removed the worker thread.  This code (except for maybe `WndProc`, depending on what the message pump does with it) all executes from the parent thread.

Comment: @Jim:  I think I explained the message pump yesterday, didn't I?

Comment: @Jim:  If I want to try to get your code running on my box, how do I tell the GUID for my usb memory stick?

Comment: @John Dibling: Sort of, but I'm still in the dark as to whether the message pump and `WndProc` operate in their own thread, or can they be deadlocked, if, for example, there is a continuous loop spinning looking for a keyboard stroke?  If that is the case, how do I get `WndProc` into its own thread?

Comment: @Jim Fell: The message pump is effectively a loop that checks for messages and calls the appropriate WndProc synchronously. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644928%28VS.85%29.aspx has some good information on them. I don't know what the context of your code is, so I'm not sure if you just need to insert a pump after RegisterForNotification or if a larger architectural change is necessary.

Comment: @Jim Fell: Is this a console application?

Comment: @John Dibling: Unfortunately, the GUID is not available through the Device Manager.  It might be accessible through the registry, but I wouldn't know where to look for it.  You might try a registry search using the manufacturer name of your USB stick.

Comment: @Jon:  He's creating windows, so I'm assuming not

Comment: @Jon: It is, but the code that I posted is located in a separate project that generates a DLL.  They are both in the same solution, whose generated .exe is a console application.

Comment: @John Dibling: It is a console application.  The window is there only to handle the `WM_DEVICECHANGE` message when my USB device is removed or inserted.  The window itself is not visible.

Comment: @Jim:  OK, I'll try to work on replicating this locally.  Might take quite some time.

Comment: @Jim:  If you're open to it, feel free to email me a zip of all your source code & project files.  You can find my email address in my profile.

Comment: @Jim Fell: Ok, that'd do it. Mixing windows and console input tends to get messy. You've got two options: Create a message pump that dispatches messages and checks for keyboard input without blocking, OR spawn a separate thread to create the window and pump messages for it. The second option is probably the less complicated of the two.

Comment: It turns out that I needed to implement a message pump on the thread.  I moved the creation of the new window and `WndProc` to a new thread, added a message pump, made another thread for polling for keyboard input (one window is more than enough trouble), and now it works!  ::does happy dance::  Jon, post your link to the MSDN website describing how to implement the message pump as your answer, and I'll accept it.  Thanks again, both of you, for all your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a message pump to retrieve the notifications from the queue and dispatch them to your WndProc. The message pump is effectively a loop that checks for messages and calls the appropriate WndProc synchronously. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644928%28VS.85%29.aspx) has some good information on them. I don't know what the context of your code is, so I'm not sure if you just need to insert a pump after RegisterForNotification or if a larger architectural change is necessary.